# Is use of global variable in my below thread is good?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have written a code which has a one thread called mulitple  time from same process and i am good with lock mechanism.

I am using a global variable bool which notify when to read a file.
**I am not sure whether use of global variable in thread is good practice or not** if not please suggest how to avoid the use of global variables in below case.

```
//global

bool lock_file_read =false;
```

// Note this thread is called  multiple time from same process is use global var is good?

```
static void * runMyScript(void *tempFile)

{
  pthread_t threads;
  lock_file_read = true;

  /* Lock mutex code */
  pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex)
  system("myscript takes around 20-30 sec");

   /* Unlock Mutex code*/
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
  lock_file_read=false;
}

void ReadFileWhen_Script_completed()
{
  if(!lock_file_read)
  {
    //read it
    //call to thread 
  }
}
```

Comment: `local_file_read` is not the same name as `lock_file_read`.  If it should be then NO; there is a mechanism for updates on one thread to be seen on another see std::atomic :  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic   Threads can NOT be called from other processes (unless IPC).

Comment: sorry my mistake i have update

Comment: wont the Lock mutex code make it safe?

Comment: Only if it is "inside" the mutex. Right now it is not ok.

Comment: @RichardCritten If it is called multiple time from the same process then is it safe?

Comment: @deviantfan if i place lock_file_read=false; before unlock mutex then it is safe?

Comment: Consider using lambda expression with *capture* so that you can get rid of the global variable.  Also consider using *std::thread* and
 *std::mutex*.

Comment: How exactly are you using the same thread in different processes?

Comment: @molbdnilo and Richard Critten I am really sorry thread is called for the multiple time from same process I have update please excuse

Comment: Why don't you use std::thread instead of pthreads?